# Python: json dump adds additional double quotes ! how to remove?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to update the value in the JSON file, after the JSON dump python adds the additional "" in value. which I am trying to remove. Can you someone help.

**raw JSON file data**

```
{
    "ProjectBranch": "Dev", 
    "BaselineRestore": {
        "releaseName": "02", 
        "useProcessedBaseline": false, 
        "incrementalRun": false, 
        "breakPipelinePostRestore": false, 
        "releaseYear": "2022", 
        "debugMode": true
    }
}
```

**my python script**

```
import os
import glob
import json
import shutil
import re

cwd = os.getcwd()
pipeline_config_file = os.path.join(cwd, "config", "test.json")

with open(pipeline_config_file, "r+") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    incrementalRun = str(data['BaselineRestore']['incrementalRun']).lower()
    data['BaselineRestore']['incrementalRun'] = 'true'
    data['BaselineRestore']['incrementalRun'] = data['BaselineRestore']['incrementalRun'].strip()
    #data = data.replace('"true"', 'true')

with open(pipeline_config_file, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

**script output**

```
{
    "ProjectBranch": "Dev", 
    "BaselineRestore": {
        "releaseName": "02", 
        "useProcessedBaseline": false, 
        "incrementalRun": "true", 
        "breakPipelinePostRestore": false, 
        "releaseYear": "2022", 
        "debugMode": true
    }
```

**Expected Data**

```
{
    "ProjectBranch": "Dev", 
    "BaselineRestore": {
        "releaseName": "02", 
        "useProcessedBaseline": false, 
        "incrementalRun": true,
        "breakPipelinePostRestore": true, 
        "releaseYear": "2022", 
        "debugMode": true
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not add any additional `""`. You define string containing `true` and it is saved as such. If you want to save an actual bool value make it an actual bool value, i.e `True` without any quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line `data['BaselineRestore']['incrementalRun'] = 'true'` places a string `'true'` here, as opposed to the `True` boolean. This is what causes the difference between the two.

You should use:

```
import os
import glob
import json
import shutil
import re

cwd = os.getcwd()
pipeline_config_file = os.path.join(cwd, "config", "test.json")

with open(pipeline_config_file, "r+") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    data['BaselineRestore']['incrementalRun'] = True

with open(pipeline_config_file, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

Assuming that your goal is to exclusively update `false` to `true` for `incrementalRun`.